# SailsJs 0.10: User.findOne({_id: id}) returning null for unique primary key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I have the following **user model**:

```
var model = module.exports = {
  autoPK: false,
  attributes: {

    id: {
        type: 'string',
        primaryKey: true
    },

    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    hash: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
   }
}
```

And the following **query** on it:

```
User.findOne({_id: req.param('user_id')}).populate('drafts').then(function(user) {
    console.log("USER: " + JSON.stringify(user) + " FOR: " + req.param('user_id'));
    res.send(user.drafts, 200);
});
```

From the print statement, I know **nothing is turning being returned for the ID "Rfrq8un5f," but the mongodb command line outputs this:**

```
> db.user.find();
{ "email" : "m@m.com", "hash" : "[...]", "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-05-18T16:32:21.023Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2014-05-18T16:32:21.023Z"), "_id" : "9PTIqHxEc" }
```

What's going on?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're searching for a user with ID "Rfrq8un5f".  Your database contains a single user, with ID "9PTIqHxEc".  So...

Comment: @ScottGress So... I'm an idiot *palm to forehead*

Comment: Nawwwwwwwww it happens ;)

Comment: A couple of other points: 1) `autoPK` doesn't have any real meaning when using sails-mongo, and 2) The adapter will automatically translate between `id` and `_id` for you.  So you don't need to explicitly configure that `id` attribute in your model, and you can query `id` rather than `_id` to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `id: null` when use waterline with mongo adapter you must add to the model: `autoPK: false, schema: true`. You need both, isn't enough with autoPK false or schema true.

This is a model example solving that issue (user model):

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  autoPK: false,
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      email: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      maxLength: 15,
      columnName: 'encrypted_password',
      required: true
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted(err, encryptedPassword) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      values.password = encryptedPassword;
      next();
    });
  }
};
```